# What does the -l in ksh -l do?

Tags: 14.04

If I use the command:

```
ksh -l
```

Does it call the file `profile.ksh`? And what does the `-l` option do?

Comment: try `man ksh` ..

Answer (score 0):

> `ksh` is a command interpreter intended for both interactive and shell
>   script use. Its command language is a superset of the sh shell
>   language.
>
> ```
> -l
> ```
>
> Login shell. If the basename the shell is called with (i.e. argv[0]) starts with ‘-’ or if this option is used, the shell is
>   assumed to be a login shell and the shell reads and executes the
>   contents of /etc/profile and $HOME/.profile if they exist and are
>   readable.<sup>[ksh-OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ksh.1?query=ksh&sec=1)</sup>

See also [ksh-Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh)

Comment: Which is the real `ksh`? `ksh` or [`ksh93`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ksh93)?

Comment: ksh93 is a newer version.  See [Q5 here](http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html).